# Take an array of id numbers and gather info from another table in alphabetical order

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to take an array list of product ids, get the associated data (which is stored in another table, I know... that is poorly set up), and then alphabetize them based on the product name.  Here is what I have thus far:

```
$set = array($aID['id']);
$getInfo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE FIND_IN_SET('$set', id) ORDER BY name ASC");
while($product = mysql_fetch_array($getInfo))
    {
        echo $product['name'] . " <br /\n";
    }
```

I am getting an error message for the while row which means something is wrong on my $getInfo query line.  What am I doing wrong?  Any help and all constructive criticism is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried echoing out your SQL statement and running it directly in the database?

Comment: Even if these ids are safe, you should parameterize the query anyway.  And while you're at it, find a mechanism that correctly parameterizes arrays. (i.e. `("SELECT ... IN (:set)", array('set' => $set))`

Comment: To add to what @SethBattin said: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Please use PDO (http://php.net/PDO)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass an array into mysql.  You need to convert it to a comma seperated string:

```
$set = array($aID['id']);
$set = implode(',' $set);
```

Also the order is reversed in your FIND_IN_SET.  It should be

```
FIND_IN_SET(id, '$set')
```

Honestly, I'd just use `IN` as FIND_IN_SET returns an index of where it is in the set, not probably what you want:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id IN ($set) ORDER BY name ASC
```

Comment: @NotJay if the set is a set of non-integers, you'll need to to quote each array element  to pass it to `IN`.

Comment: @NotJay see this how to implode an array and quote the values: http://melikedev.com/2010/02/24/php-wrap-implode-array-elements-in-quotes/

Comment: That does not seem to help... still getting the same error message

Comment: Can you echo out the final query string and add that and the error to your question or comment?

Comment: We forgot the comma in the implode between the single quote and the variable!

Comment: @NotJay Awesome, glad it fixed your issue!

Answer (score 0):

I think that it takes $set as part of mysql query. You should show that it is an external variable from php like this:

```
$getInfo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE FIND_IN_SET('.$set.', id) ORDER BY name ASC");
```

Comment: `$set` is an array .. it will just print `Array`and the query will still be invalid

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `IN`

```
$ids = implode(",",$set);
$getInfo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id IN (".$id.") ORDER BY name ASC");
```